# Internet Explorer Inputbox alignment

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have many quantity input boxes below each other for each product listed with a button to increase and decrease quantities next to it.

 The problem I'm having is that in Internet Explorer (11) when I use the increase or decrease button the numbers line up correctly, but if I change the quantity manually (keyboard entry), it does not line up with the other items.

**Normal Entry (using the increase/decrease button)**
[image]

**Keyboard Entry (shown by arrow)**
[image]

I simply have the following css styles added to this inputbox:

```
display: block;
float: left;
margin-top: 2px;
text-align: right;
padding: 5px 10px;
```

Comment: Please provide your **HTML** too OR create a **JSFiddle**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, turns out it was the meta tag below that was causing the issue, removed it and the entire websites styling improved.

```
<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
```